# Noob Questions - Database approach

Tags: postgresql, mongodb, ddl

I have a database of "records" that relate to photos - title, location, text, tags, etc. I am now adding more fields for other media types, videos for example will get an transcript, audio will get chapters.

I have been using Postgres until now and it works well but now my schema is moving towards a NoSQL model - each "record" conforms to two or three shapes.

Part of my wants to keep the data relational as there is the odd join - a record is a part of a collection, for example. However, I am struggling to see how full text search and unique ids across multiple tables would work - it seems as if the normalisation approach would have an images table, an audio table, a video table.

Any sage advice you can offer would be appreciated. I have the data in MongoDB and it *works* but I am not sure if I have missed a trick somewhere.

Comment: I would go for a hybrid approach: put all attributes that are common into regular columns. And create one column of type `jsonb` to store the type specific, dynamic attributes. Postgres' full text search can deal with jsonb values

Comment: That's quite sensible - my worry is that the more that gets added to the Jsonb column the more I should just use NoSQL. I think I am put off by Internet chatter against the NoSQL approach, and the relative experience with it.

Comment: Postgres' JSON support is pretty outstanding. If you worry that the JSON values get too big in Postgres, they would be too big in MongoDB as well.

Comment: Deffo go with PostgreSQL - it's the best of both worlds! Many NoSQL systems are scrambling in one way or another - Michael Stonebraker thinks that NoSQL throws the baby out with the bathwater. With PostgreSQL, you get to keep a very sophisticated and battle-hardened SQL engine/optimiser and use JSON when you feel it's necessary!

Comment: Yes, I am mapping out my data now to see just where the worlds separate - I am starting to think that this is just an attempt to avoid some hard work at the start! I assume that the hard work will need to be done but it will just come later if I avoid the data design bit now!